# Compile apache 2.2.23 on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS with openssl error

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, openssl

I have (or am) moved from OpenSuse 12.1 to Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS -- I have had no problems compiling apache from source on our OpenSUSE boxes.. However, I have run into a problem with Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS.

I have installed openssl, libssl-dev and when I attempt to compile apache, I receive the following:

> checking for SSL/TLS toolkit base... /usr
>
> checking for SSL/TLS toolkit version... OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
>
> checking for SSL/TLS toolkit includes... /usr/include
>
> checking for SSL/TLS toolkit libraries... configure: error: OpenSSL libraries not found

I have attempted to use --with-ssl=/usr/include/openssl but that did not work either.

Do I need to compile SSL from source as well (I did not need to do this on our SUSE boxes).

Thank You.

Note : I am required to compile Apache for various business reasons, using apt-get apache2 is not an option for me.

Edit : I have libssl.so.1.0.0 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu and configure option --libdir=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

Comment: Does *business reasons* == *PCI compliance*?

Comment: various source changes from our dev team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile openssl, then compile and link Apache against --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl (the default path). Don't forget "--enable-so"

I had many issue with the maintainer libs from debian distros and always compile openssl from scratch.

If you are using PHP and use --with-openssl=/usr/local/ssl, the same libraries have to be used.